# How to make proper redirect to Play Store on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile

On Chrome mobile after version 40 deeplinking isn't working. more info in [Why Has Google Broken Deeplinking on Android?](http://blog.tapstream.com/why-has-google-broken-deeplinking-on-android/)

The Intent URLs  can no longer be triggered from on-page JavaScript, so `window.location` ; `window.redirect` won't work with `market//` deeplink.

Is there some interesting solution, that can handle this now?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html):

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

So for example, Google Maps:

```
market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps
```

I've just tried this on a development app of mine and this seems to work as intended.

[Working example](http://codepen.io/Jarrrk/pen/ENPrgB)

Comment: yes, if you need click by user, but I need go to market as redirect on page load for example. On click user redirects on my tracking system and then I redirect him to market.